# TypeError: this.networkService.getRequest(...).pipe is not a function in ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4, rxjs-observables

Clicking on second tab in a tab bar shows this error:

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.networkService.getRequest(...).pipe is not a function
TypeError: this.networkService.getRequest(...).pipe is not a function
at PaymentService.getPaymentList (payment.service.ts:359)
at PaymentComponent.loadDataPaymentState (payment.component.ts:188)
at PaymentComponent.ngAfterViewInit (payment.component.ts:130)
```

Two pages in these tabs are using PaymentComponent. Everything works in the tab which is first open. Clicking on second tab causes error.

The code on which error occurs is :

```
getpaymentList() {
let list = this.buildListURL();
return this.networkService.getRequest(list).pipe(
  tap(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data);
   
      this.lastbill= data["bill"];
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(" error");
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
);
```

}

The code of getRequest:

```
getRequest(path, customHeader?) {
let options = this.createOptions();
if (customHeader) {
  options.headers = this.jsonConcat(options.headers, customHeader);
}

if (!this.isOnline) {
  this.errorOccurred(null);
}
let cachedData = this.cacheService.getCachedNode(path);
if (cachedData) {
  return cachedData;
} else {
  return this.http
    .get(
      path,
      options
    )
    .pipe(
      map(
        (data) => {
          console.log("data");
          return data;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("error");
          console.log(error);
          this.errorOccurred(error);
        }
      )
    );
}
```

}

I am not able to figure out what is the issue. If anyone have an idea about it then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Change `getRequest(path, customHeader?)` to `getRequest(path, customHeader?): Observable<YourType>` and tell us if it fixes your pipe-problem, but breaks your `getRequest` method.

Comment: @Silvermind it gives the same error after changing getRequest(path, customHeader?) to getRequest(path, customHeader?): Observable<any>

Comment: You might have your typings wrong. Try disabling the cache-system and always return the http logic. If that fixes it, you should check your caching mechanics.

Comment: @Silvermind you are right, there is something wrong with caching mechanism after disabling cache it works

Comment: it sounds like the cachedData can't be piped off of.  Can you try wrapping it with the of RxJS operator like: return of(cachedData) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving error because calling method expects an observable when first time you call **getRequest** method there is no data in a cache and data in **else clause** get called but when this function get called next time then there is a data in a cache and **if (cachedData) clause** get called but

```
if (cachedData) {
   return cachedData;
}
```

is not returning observable.

If you will do small changes in it then it will also work with cache code. You have to do following things:

1. First:

   ```
   import { of } from "rxjs";
   ```
2. make few changes in **getRequest** method, instead of

   ```
   if (cachedData) {
      return cachedData;
   }
   ```

write

```
   if (cachedData) {
       return of(cachedData);
   }
```